# horizontal line on wpftoolkit chart

Tags: c#-4.0, wpftoolkit

I'm using the WPF toolkit to create a line graph.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<Window x:Class="TempDataAnalyzer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
     <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Temperature" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
     </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> entries = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 0));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 23));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 45));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 46));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 71));

        lineChart.DataContext = entries;
    }
}
```

this question was already asked, but i didnt understand the answer, could some one please provide me with an example

Comment: how to show horizontal line at a specific  point, in my example, i want to show a dark line at 35

Comment: got the answer here is the link it has good example [Goal Line](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/silverlight-chart-with-a-goal-line/)